# Page flickering on ad refresh in WP 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, flicker, google-advertising-id

I have used Googleadmob sdk in the app for ads. When ever the ad changes, there is a flicker on the screen? It is evident on black background and not so much on the white.

**EDIT**

```
private void AdLoaded(object sender, GoogleAds.AdEventArgs e)
{
  if (AdBorder.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
  {
     AdBorder.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed; // Element to show dummy ads for certain conditions
  }
   AdView1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; // Google Adview
}
```

I have a sliding menu(Facebook like menu). The menu is nothing but a canvas which is moved to achieve the effect. The background on this menu is a dark image. Only this menu has the flicker. When the menu is closed, and the ad refreshes in the main part, no flicker happens

anyone knows why it is happening? or any workarounds to fix the flicker?

Comment: is there some code that we could look at that might help us figure it out?

Comment: @GiliusMaximus I have updated with some code